# How to Move Linux partition but keep the dual boot

Tags: linux, partitioning, multi-boot, uefi, arch-linux

have a Windows 10 and Arch Linux dual boot system on my 1 TB m.2 ssd. Because I have a lot of games in Windows, I got myself another 1 TB Samsung 860 evo. I would like to move my entire Linux partition to the new ssd and free up some space for Windows 10. I have grub 2 and `UEFI` is mounted to `/boot/efi/`. So how would I go about keeping the same system but moving everything in the Arch linux partition to the new ssd. Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: You have to clone the Linux partition / partitions to the new SSD with something like EaseUs ToDo Backup from within Windows. Start Windows fire up EaseUs and clone everything from ArchLinux to the new SSD. You will need to repair the boot for Linux afterwards. I use Ubuntu so its easy to repair it by installing boot-repair from a live USB. Its also possible to move Windows to the new partition, after which you may have to repair the Windows installation from the Windows USB, downfall is that you will have to repair the Linux boot also.

Comment: It should be possible to use an Ubuntu live USB and install boot repair to repair ArchLinux, but I have not tried it and I can't guarantee.

Comment: That is really helpful info and I will try that out. Thank a lot.